# Relative layout to Bitmap image conversion

Tags: android, bitmap, android-layout

i set background image to relativelayout and add some text in that layer. now i want to save the image into bitmap.so give me idea about this?.

Comment: You want to save the visual representation of the RelativeLayout to a bitmap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)